# Chrome 38: networkPredictionEnabled not accessible

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that disallows networkPredictionEnabled like this:

`chrome.privacy.network.networkPredictionEnabled.set({ value: false })`

If I execute it on the extension console it works properly on Chrome 32, but it doesn't on Chrome 38. I've done some research and I've seen that in chrome://settings the checkbox has changed its name from Chrome 32

`<input id="dnsPrefetchingEnabled" metric="Options_DnsPrefetchCheckbox" type="checkbox" pref="dns_prefetching.enabled">`

to Chrome 38

`<input id="networkPredictionOptions" metric="Options_DnsPrefetchCheckbox" type="checkbox">`

Chrome.privacy.network nor chrome.privacy objects have any other "Prediction" settings.

The only thing that I've found is this issue regarding Chromium, but nothing about Chrome.
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423748

Is it possible that the didn't remove the object networkPredictionEnabled and didn't add the new one "networkPredictionOptions"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium is the project name (and also a name of browsers that are directly build from Chromium's source code), Google Chrome is the product name (build from Chromium's source code plus some closed-source additions by Google).

The bug report that you've cited applies to Google Chrome as well, and the bug has been fixed since Google Chrome 39.0.2171.56. Google Chrome 39 will soon be promoted to the stable channel, so if you wait a few more days, then your extension will work again.

Comment: Thanks @RobW for the clarification and the solution. I assume that no patch will be applied to version 38 to fix this, right?

Comment: @xavi Nope. Old Chrome versions are not updated. The only supported Chrome versions are stable and up, and since 39 is soon going to be stable, 38 will then not be patched any more.